# Using same version number for multiple Xcode targets Info.plist

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, plist

I have a single Xcode project with multiple targets.

Each target has its own `Info.plist` file with the version number of that application. (`CFBundleVersion` and `CFBundleShortVersionString`)

How can I use single, common Version Number and Build Number source for each target, rather than editing each target's plist file?

Comment: Is this the best of ideas? What would happen if you need a fix for one of the targets but not all of them would you do a release for all the targets?

Comment: I shouldnt ever need a fix for just one of the targets, except maybe a logo replacement which should rarely happen.

Comment: Still there is an an occasion (however rare it is) that this could happen. Obviously it is your decision though I was enquirying into whether it was your best option.

Comment: The way I do my incrementing of version number is done through a shell script (Share shell script) that will run on whichever target is being built in production. This does have issues though as well. Such as the format for our version is `1.0.0` the script will only increment the last digit as we make very rare major changes which will affect the second digit and make even less changes that are overhauls which would affect the first digit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add a new custom property to your project (`Editor` -> `Add Build Setting` -> `Add User Defined Setting`). Let's name it `MY_VERSION` and let's give it value `1.0.1`.

Now go to the `Info` section of every target and set the version to `${MY_VERSION}`.

Comment: I do have a Settings.plist file that all my targets use, I suppose that is a good place to add it?

Comment: Unstable solution. Any editing in 'General' tab of version (field not disabled) breaks this binding.

Comment: @Argus Well, you have to know that you are using a property. There is no better solution. Anyway, this solution is 7 years old but I am still using it for some projects, especially when the version is different depending on build configuration.

Answer (score 28):

The following works with Xcode 12 and does not require User-Defined variables.

1. Select your project
2. Select Build Settings and find "Versioning"
3. Set "Marketing Version" to be your version
4. Set "Current Project Version" to be your build

[image: Update project]

---

5. Next, select each of your targets
6. Delete/remove any version number and it will use the default "Marketing Version"
7. Delete/remove any build number and it will use the default "Current Project Version"
8. Do this for all of your targets

[image: Update targets]

---

Once you do this, you only need to update the "Marketing Version" and "Current Project Version" for the Project and all of your targets will be updated accordingly.

Comment: I'm getting the following warning for a Widget extension. Both my versions are set to nothing, per your suggestion. Any idea?
The CFBundleShortVersionString of an app extension (null) must match that of its containing parent app (null)